# Is it possible to figure out what Apple ID is now associated with my MacBook Pro using its serial number?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud

My MacBook Pro was stolen. Is it possible to figure out what Apple ID is now associated with my MacBook Pro using its serial number? Is there a way I can still track down my macbook pro in the event that the one who took or "borrowed" my MBP... 1) Did not connect to the internet 2) Clean installed the OS (boot from USB, then reformatted the Hard Drive/Macintosh HD) 3) Reset the PRAM and NVRAM 4) Installed his own or new Apple ID credentials to iCloud I really just need to know realistically, if whoever took it did this. Is there still a chance I can get it back or at least track its location or who has it.